# Nodejs, Binance API : Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, binance

I have encountered an issue where the API starts giving error that the timestamp for the request is outside of `recvWindow`.

First, a few requests are fine I get the intended result but then I suddenly start getting errors for timestamps.

Below is a code snippet that mimics the continuous requests to the API:

```
//main file
const BinanceAPI = require(./BinanceAPI.js);

const binanceAPI = new BinanceAPI();

let data = {
  p1: {
    tradePair: 'BNBBTC',
    tradePairData: {
      lastupdate: 1610127918784,
      b: '0.00102880',
      B: '48.80000000',
      a: '0.00102920',
      A: '2.35000000',
      u: 1178490919,
    },
    bid: 0,
  }
  inArr: ['0.1000000'], 
  outArr: [0.0024186200000000002],
  priceArr: ['0.0010520'], ///
  qtyArr: ['2.35000000'],
  bidArr: [0, 1, 0],
};


async function executeTrade() {
  data.calculationEndTime = new Date().getTime();
  data.id = data.p1.tradePair + '_' + data.calculationEndTime;

  if (data.bidArr[0] == 1) {
      binanceAPI.setNewOrder(
      data.p1.tradePair,
      data.outArr[0],
      data.priceArr[0],
      'SELL',
      insertResponse(id, data.p1.tradePair),
      id
    );
  } else {
    binanceAPI.setNewOrder(
      data.p1.tradePair,
      data.inArr[0],
      data.priceArr[0],
      'BUY',
      insertResponse(id, data.p1.tradePair),
      id
    );
  }
}


setInterval(executeTrade, 200);
```

And I am using **binance-api-node** package for calling Binance API

Below is the code where the request is taking place

```
//Binance API
class BinanceAPI {

  constructor() {
    this.counter = 0;
  }

async setNewOrder(symbol, quantitiy, price, side, cb, id) {
    
    let client = new Binance({
      apiKey: API_KEY,
      apiSecret: API_SECRET,
      // getTime: this.getTime(this.timeOffset),
    });

    client
      .order({
        symbol: symbol,
        side: side,
        quantity: quantitiy,
        price: price,
        timeInForce: 'FOK',
        type: 'LIMIT',
      })
      .then(cb)
      .catch(cb);

  }
}

module.exports = BinanceAPI;
```

For first few request I get proper response but then the timestamp error , code -1021 starts showing.

Comment: hi @Parth did you get a solution for this issue.